# Without format specifiers, converting binary int number to hexadecimal in C

Tags: c, function, binary, hex

There is a point in my program where I want to convert a binary number into a hexadecimal number, which I am having a lot of trouble with. I am converting this number into a hexadecimal number *without* any format specifiers, coding the actual conversion.

I have researched how to do this by hand, from videos such as this Khan Academy tutorial: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/applying-math-reasoning-topic/alternate-number-bases/v/binary-to-hexadecimal

I understand the conversion in a mathematical sense, but translating this into code confuses me.

What I have so far is the function call. I have already have a binary of type integer. I need to send that into a function which will return its hexadecimal equivalent. Since hexadecimal values can be represented by a-f, A-F characters, then I do not think returning back an integer from the function is valid. So the function must return a char pointer or char array that contains the converted hexadecimal value. Here's my plan for the function call:

```
char * hexAnswer;
hexAnswer = binaryToHex(answer) //answer is the binary number of type int
```

The problem I'm having is with the function code itself for the binary to hex conversion. Now, my thought process for the conversion is as follows:

Step 1: segment the integer into groups of 4. 
Step 2: convert the binary segments of 4 with its hexadecimal equivalent:

```
char * binaryToHex(int n)
{
   //break into groups of 4
   //send group of 4 to switch statement of equivalent hexadecimal conversion
   //append the converted groups together

    //Return hex number

}
```

Here is the switch statement:

```
char * IndividualBinToHex (/*The group of 4 binary digits*/) {

switch (/*group of 4 binary digits*/) {
    case '0000':
        return "0";
        break;
    case '0001':
        return "1";
        break;

    case '00010':
        return "2";
        break;

    case '0011':
        return "3";
        break;

    case '0100':
        return "4";
        break;

    case '0101':
        return "5";
        break;

    case '0110':
        return "6";
        break;

    case '0111':
        return "7";
        break;

    case '1000':
        return "8";
        break;

    case '1001':
        return "9";
        break;

    case '1010':
        return "A";
        break;

    case '1010':
        return "a";
        break;

    case '1011':
         return "B";
         break;

    case '1100':
        return "C";
        break;

    case '1101':
        return "D";
        break;

    case '1110':
        return "E";
        break;

    case '1111':
        return "F";
        break;
     }
   }
```

I'm still a bit confused of what the function body will specifically hold. Thanks for any help you can send my way.

Comment: No offense, but: You should first read a good C book or tutorial. Your code shows significant missunderstanding of the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic idea:

```
int raw_input;      // int to convert
// convert to unsigned to have defined shifting operations
unsigned int input=(unsigned int) raw_input;
static const char xlate[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
static const int digits=2*sizeof (unsigned int);
char answer[3+digits];
answer [0]="0";
answer [1]="x";
int shift=4*digits;
for (int i = 0; i < digits; ++i)
{
   shift-=4;
   int nibble=(input >> shift) & 0xF;
   answer [2+i]=xlate [nibble];
}
answer [2+digits]='\0';
```

Just shift the nibble and mask it off and then translate it using a lookup table to characters.

Comment: Try to convert `0x12345678`.

Comment: Also: shifting a negative integer is _implementation defined_. And the size of an `int` can be 16 bits upwards. What if `int` does not use 2s complement?

Comment: It's not to show _all_ actually, but you should show correct code, or list the constraints of your code. Basically, I would use `unsigned` and explain the cast. Negative Hex makes no sense imo. Then reserve an array according to the required size (what if `int` is 64 bits). And for shifting a loop would be the better approach, as that can care about different sizes and will be shorter. Not to talk about the lookup-table being `static const` - `const` should be clear, `static` to avoid re-initialization for each call and using up stack space.

Comment: So little code, so much to think about ;-) - no offense, just a statement. Somethimes I hate C for that. But then I love it 5 minutes for allowing things other languages don't (that easy).

Comment: You are aware of `CHAR_BIT` and its background? :-) OkOk, I think you made enough effort for such a simple question. I see much of a problem OP still has too little background to understand what you are actually doing and why (that's the reason I commented so massively).

Comment: @Olaf No +1?  Lol, i mostly did this because of fear of people reading the other answer.  Also might want to unwind some comments

Comment: Just think why I commented on your answer and not the other. But, ok, +1 as a bonus for accepting my nit-pickyness (not sure if that really is a valid word, but hope you get what I mean)

Comment: I'd actually leave the comments to show how much one has to think about. I was actually quite surpriised myself what came together for that little code (my comment was really an expression of surprise, not criticism).

Answer (score -2):

This solution is taken from Martin James' (in the comments). His solution is far superior to what this answer was initially.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

const char* hexlat="0123456789ABCDEF";

char * binaryToHex(unsigned int answer, char * result)
{ 
    if( answer == 0 ) return result; 
    else 
    { 
        // shift next nibble bits into rightmost nibble and recurse
        result=binaryToHex( answer>>4, result );
        // AND with last 4 bits, and get hex char to assign to current char
        *result = hexlat[answer & 0x0F];
        // return current char pointer + 1 to parent call
        return result+1; 
    } 
};

int main(void) 
{ 
    unsigned int answer = 0x12340ADF;
    char hexAnswer[ 32 ];
    // note the '\0' null terminates the end of the string
    // since binaryToHex recursively returns the char index + 1
    *binaryToHex( answer, hexAnswer ) = '\0';
    printf( "%s", hexAnswer );
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That looks awfully complicated.

Comment: But really, I would appreciate comments on why its complex, and suggestions for improvement. Also is it incorrect? and if so, how?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

const char* hexlat="0123456789ABCDEF";

char *binaryToHex(int answer, char *result){
  if(answer==0) return result;
  else{
    result=binaryToHex(answer>>4,result);
    *result=hexlat[answer & 0x0F];
    return result+1;
  }
};

int main(void) {
 int answer=0x12340ADF;
 char hexAnswer[32];
 *binaryToHex(answer,hexAnswer)='\0';
 printf("%s",hexAnswer);
 return 0;
}

Comment: @MartinJames that's a thing of beauty

Comment: @Catalyst it would have been even more stunning if I had used unsigned ints to avoid the UB of shifting negative numbers~;)